# listbox selected item winform

Tags: winforms

Listbox.SelectedItem = value does not work for me. Actually I want to change selection programmatically. I do not have the index of the Listbox to be selected but the Text only. Actually the displaymember is provided by combo box. when the selection changes in the combo box the resulting changes is to be reflected on listbox as well.

```
      void PopulateList()
    {
        this.list.DataSource = (IList)ClassDsnManager.GetDataSourceNames();
        this.list.DisplayMember = "Name";
        this.list.ValueMember = "Driver";

    }
 void ComboSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (Combo.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            ClassDatabase selecteditem = (ClassDatabase)Combo.SelectedItem;

            source.Text = selecteditem.source;

            string destination= selecteditem.SqlConn;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(destination))
            {
                string[] connectionValue = connection.Split(Convert.ToChar(";"));
                string dsnName = connectionValue[0].Substring(4, connectionValue[0].Length - 4);
                // this is the list box whose value i want to set
                lbDSN.SelectedItem = dsnName;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: It'd help if you showed the code you use to populate the list box

Comment: @JohnArlen Could you please see it i have pasted the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution1:** In the `SelectedIndexChanged` of `Combobox` simply write

```
listBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

**Solution2:** Change the **`DropDownStyle`** of `Combobox` to `Simple`. It will show the `Combobox` like a `Listbox`.